# React Promise not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-promise

I am calling an action creator and sending it to the reducer and using react promise to handle the promise. But I am getting an error, and unsure how to fix it or where to look in my code.

```
this.props.loginUser(props)
.then(() => {
  console.log("success");
}).catch(error =>{
  console.log(error);
});
```

Error:

```
<body> tried to unmount. Because of cross-browser quirks it is impossible to unmount some top-level components (eg <html>, <head>, and <body>) reliably and efficiently. To fix this, have a single top-level component that never unmounts render these elements.
```

Mount React App:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('app'));
```

index.html

```
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: The error is not related to the Promise but to React. Paste the code where you mount the whole React app.

Comment: @CharlieBrown I added where I mount the react app. I do a `document.getElementById('app')`

Comment: I meant paste your "app mounting" code not the HTML code where the app gets mounted. Your call to ReactDOM.render :)

Comment: Ah ok, updated the question.

Comment: The error is so weird that it looks that one of your route components is using some tags like `head` or `body` inside it. But I still don't see the actual HTML you're `rendering` because you pasted the Router instead of the **actual component** that is/should be rendered when the error is thrown. :)

Comment: Thanks, that last comment helped me locate the error!

Comment: @CharlieBrown he is not having the Route, only the Router which is strange. The Route should hold the actual components.

Comment: @joethemow, do you still need the answer ... ?

Comment: Nope I got it thanks though and also the routes with the component are stored in a separate file.